# SQL: how do you look for missing ids?

Tags: sql, database

Suppose I have a table with lots of rows identified by a unique ID. Now I have a (rather large) user-input list of ids (**not** a table) that I want to check are already in the database.

So I want to output the ids that are in my list, but not in the table. How do I do that with SQL?

**EDIT: I know I can do that with a temporary table, but I'd really like to avoid that if possible.**

**EDIT: Same comment for using an external programming language.**

Comment: What do you mean by rather large list?

Comment: I'll try to give an example: imagine marketing sends me an email with a list of custommer ids, and I have to check that all of these IDs are present in a database table. Does that make sense?

Comment: Which programming language do you plan to use to extract list from email and query database?

Comment: @Marco: I use python, but I already know I can solve the problem with Python. I'd like to find a pure SQL solution because I feel it would be more correct and probably offer better performance if the data is large.

Comment: I don't think a pure SQL solution, if there even is one without resorting to the use of a temporary table, would really offer better performance in this case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try with this:

```
SELECT t1.id FROM your_list t1
LEFT JOIN your_table t2
  ON t1.id = t2.id
WHERE t2.id IS NULL
```

Comment: Could you give the exact syntax for "your_list"?

Comment: @static_rtti: in my mind your_list is a table in which you have all your ids to check

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not the case. Consider it user input, for example.

Comment: @static_rtti: you could insert your list in a temporary table and use my query

Comment: Why a downvote? Is there something wrong in my query? Please, explain so I can correct it...

Comment: wouldn't I need special permissions for that? In any case, that's precisely what I wanted to avoid when I asked this question. I find it pretty hard to believe there isn't a more straightforward answer to this problem.

Comment: please don't take the downvote personally, I just don't want people to think my question is answered (yet). I'll remove it later, and I'm still very grateful for your answer.

Comment: @static_rtti: I don't mind the downvote, I just liked to understand if there was something wrong. In your question you did not mention the fact you don't have a table (you edited it later). Anyway, I'm thinking if there's something better...

Comment: sorry, I didn't think of that limitation right away, your answer helped me refine my question. Anyways, thanks for thinking about my problem!

Comment: @static_rtti: sorry, I have to give up. I tried many things without success, nor web helped me. Sorry, my answer is the max I can do...

Comment: well, thanks a lot for your efforts. I guess I'll offer a bounty to make sure there really is no solution. (minor note: could you make a minor edit to your answer so I can remove my downvote? thanks!)

Comment: @static_rtti: I can absolutely make some minor edit... but which one? I really do not see something wrong, even if I remember your comment *give the exact syntax for "your_list"*... what's wrong? Do you want `AS` keyword to be present? In MySQL it's not necessary... Do you prefer I explicitly show `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE`? I'm open to any suggest :)

Comment: I've given more thought to my problem, and I think CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE really is the solution I was looking for. The only thing that bugs me is that it doesn't seem to be standard.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't mentioned:

- which RDBMS will be used;
- what is the source of the IDs.

So I will consider PostgreSQL is used, and IDs to be checked are loaded into a (*temporary*) table.

Consider the following:

```
CREATE TABLE test (id integer, value char(1));
INSERT INTO test VALUES (1,'1'), (2,'2'), (3,'3');

CREATE TABLE temp_table (id integer);
INSERT INTO temp_table VALUES (1),(5),(10);
```

You can get your results like this:

```
SELECT * FROM temp_table WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT id FROM test WHERE id = temp_table.id);
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM temp_table WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM test);
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM temp_table LEFT JOIN test USING (id) WHERE test.id IS NULL;
```

You can pick any option, depending on your volumes you may have different performance.

Just a note: some RDBMS may have limitation on the number of expressions specified literally inside `IN()` construct, keep this in mind (I hit this several times with ORACLE).

**EDIT:** In order to match constraints of *no temp tables* and *no external languages* you can use the following construct:

```
SELECT DISTINCT b.id
  FROM test a RIGHT JOIN (
       SELECT 1 id UNION ALL
       SELECT 5 UNION ALL
       SELECT 10) b ON a.id=b.id
 WHERE a.id IS NULL;
```

Unfortunately, you'll have to generate lot's of `SELECT x UNION ALL` entries to make a single-column and many-rows table here. I use `UNION ALL` to avoid unnecessary sorting step.

Comment: I don't think I have the necessary SQL permissions to create tables. Obviously, I'll still take that road if there is no other solution, but I find this hard to believe...

Comment: In case the RDBMS matters, I'm using MySQL, but I'd much prefer a portable solution. The source of the list of IDs is a user-input list, which is not in the database.

Answer (score 1):

It is hardly possible to make a single pure and general SQL query for your task, since it requires to work with a list (which is not a relational concept and standard set of list operations is too limited). For some DBMSs it is possible to write a single SQL query, but it will utilize SQL dialect of the DBMS and will be specific to the DBMS.

Comment: In that case a MySQL-only solution would be acceptable. But for example the IN operator takes a list of things, so SQL does allow "lists" at least for some types of queries.

Comment: @static_rtti: Thus I wrote that standard set of list operations is too limited.

Comment: I am not familiar with MySQL syntax. I briefly looked to the reference manual and don't see any way to write a single query. Either a temporal table with ids from your list has to be created or a possible query should operated on each id separately.